# Fill std::set at compile time?

Tags: c++, static, compilation, set, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to create (possibly `const`) `std::set` that would be filled with elements at compile time?

I am wondering about `std::set`/`std::unordered_set` specifically, not a set of templated functions that would emulate behaviour of a set.

Comment: Not with guarantees. Otherwise, in some cases, a compiler could optimize it to compile time, but I doubt any does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

`std::set` and `std::unordered_set` were designed as runtime containers, they use allocators and more importantly none of their constructor is marked as `constexpr` (even the ones taking an `std::initializer_list`), which means you can never construct one at compile time.